# Swift Parsing String to Date

Tags: ios, swift, date, format

I already tried to find a solution but nothing work.

This is my function

```
 static func parseDate(_ time: String) -> Date
 {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm a"

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

        return dateFormatter.date(from: time)!
}
```

And this is the string which I'm using to test: "23/Nov/2017 09:07 AM"

The problem is with "a" in dateFormat. For some reason is not parsing and I'm getting nil everytime that I'm trying to parse AM/PM. Because If I remove AM/PM or "a" then is working fine.

Comment: Do not set the `dateStyle`. Just set the `dateFormat`.

Comment: And since you have a fixed date string with English text, you must set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: Seems like setting en_US_POSIX fixed the issue.